# Provider Throw Errors in InitState. Provider.of<SomeProvider>(context)

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I access the context for the Provider in the initState

I keep getting the error

```
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
flutter: inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_Provider<ProductProvider>) or inheritFromElement() was called before
flutter: _ProductDetailsPageState.initState() completed.
```

Whenever I run the code below

```
if (Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context).selectedProduct == null) {
      product = Product();
      product.isReturnable = true;
      product.isActive = true;
      product.premiumType = "None Selected";
      product.category = 'None Selected';
      product.principal = 'None Selected';
    } else {
      product = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context).selectedProduct;
    }
```

N.B. the above code worked perfectly when I used the Scoped Model, however, user the Provider Model and Package throws an exception.

What I need it to access the provider before the build process, because contents of the provider are needed to build the UI.

Answer (score 4):

`Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false).selectedProduct` and ensure there are no NotifyListeners in the initState call.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Isn't it a bit weird that you need to set `listen: false` even though it isn't a ListenableProvider? I mean what would it be listening to when not set to false?

Comment: @Jonas the current widget listens by default. When `NotifyListeners()` is called, the widget will rebuild if `listen` is not set to `false`

Answer (score 1):

Try to postpone this call with `Future.delayed(...)`

Comment: Hi siega, that would work but that too has some issues. The solution is:`Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false).selectedProduct` and ensure there are no NotifyListeners in the initState call.

Answer (score 1):

Use Simon's `AfterLayout` package https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout and call it in the function you need to implement. It will be called after `Build()` has been run