# Flutter Looping Endlessly when adding a FutureBuilder Inside another FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Stop Watch timer in a Flutter Screen which works as required in the beginning inside a FutureBuilder but when I add another futurebuilder to add information from an API it keeps looping indefinitely:

Initially when I opened the screen it was looping indefinelty then when I adjusted the code it looped endlessly only when I clicked the Start button, it continued looping even after clicking the stop button.

Here is the dart file:

```
class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  bool isStartButtonDisabled = false;
  bool isStopButtonDisabled = true;
  Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
  String _elapsedTime = "00:00:00";
  late Timer _timer;
void _startStopwatch() {
    print("void _startStopwatch() { Starting stopwatch");
    _stopwatch.start();
    setState(() {
      isStartButtonDisabled = true;
      isStopButtonDisabled = false;
    });

    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      (Timer timer) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _elapsedTime = _stopwatch.elapsed.toString().split(".")[0];
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Here is ui

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                GFButton(
                  onPressed: isStartButtonDisabled ? null : startWorkout,
                  text: "Start Workout",
                ),
                Text(
                  _elapsedTime,
                ),
                Card(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0), //change here
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      FutureBuilder<List<Model_No_1>>(
                        future: futureModel_No_1,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<List<Model_No_1>> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Column(
                              children: List.generate(snapshot.data!.length,
                                  (int index) {
                                String Some_VariableName =
                                    snapshot.data![index].name;
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      snapshot.data![index].name,
                                    ),
                                    Builder(builder: (context) {
                                      return Container(
                                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                            child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            Card(
                                              child: Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: FutureBuilder<
                                                        Get_Old_Model_No>(
                                                      future: () {
                                                        final Map<String,dynamic>                                                            arguments =ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String,dynamic>;final int id =arguments['id'] ??
0;print("This is the id $id");return APIService.Get_Old_Model_No(id);}(),builder:(context, snapshot) {print("Snapshot data:${snapshot.data}");print("Snapshot error:${snapshot.error}");
                                                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                                          return Column(
                                                            children: [
                                                              // Text(snapshot
                                                              //     .data
                                                              //     ?.endDate),
                                                            ],
                                                          );
                                                        } else if (snapshot
                                                            .hasError) {
                                                          return Text(
                                                              "${snapshot.error}");
                                                        }
                                                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                                      },),),],),),
for (var breakdown in snapshot.data![index].breakdowns)
Form(child: Expanded(child: Column(children: [TextFormField(
keyboardType:TextInputType.number,
onChanged:(value) {
final int?parsedValue =
int.tryParse(value);if (parsedValue !=
null) {setState(
() {variable1 =parsedValue;});} else {}
},),],),),),
```

When I add the Expanded, which runs the APIService.Get_Old_Model_No(id);

My question is why is the indefinete looping happening? How can I fix it ?

Comment: If you don't want to use `bloc library` or `provider` .. at least use `ValueListenableBuilder` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html


this page has very bad approach. you need to refresh a text widget so only refresh  the text widget **NOT** whole of page. after each `setstate` the `build` method runs and builds all widgets.  I think this change will solve your other problems.

Comment: Flutter can call build method 60 times per second, making an API call inside build is basically doing DDoS attack to your server. Move the API call somewhere, like initState, and then give Future to FutureBuilder. Not a function. You need to change this architecture. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664293/futurebuilder-runs-twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setState` the build method is called, this triggers the `FutureBulder` to rebuild, thereby calling the future again.

What I see happening in your case is that once the `_startStopwatch` is called, the timer is started and it calls `setState` every second. I can't see your stop function, but it seems you are not canceling the `Timer.periodic` when you stop the stopWatch.

To solve your problem, you need to manage your state in such a way that only the necessary widget rebuild when the state changes. To achieve this you will need more than `setState`. See a simple example below using `ValueNotifier` and `ValueListenableBuilder`.

```
class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
 ValueNotifier<bool> isStartButtonDisabled = ValueNotifier(false);
 ValueNotifier<bool> isStopButtonDisabled = ValueNotifier(true);

 Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
 ValueNotifier<String> _elapsedTime = ValueNotifier("00:00:00");

 late Timer _timer;
 void _startStopwatch() {
  print("void _startStopwatch() { Starting stopwatch");
  _stopwatch.start();
  
    isStartButtonDisabled.value = true;
    isStopButtonDisabled.value = false;
  

  _timer = Timer.periodic(
   const Duration(seconds: 1),
   (Timer timer) {
     if (mounted) {
       
        _elapsedTime.value = _stopwatch.elapsed.toString().split(".")[0];
       
      }
     },
    );
   }

   @override
   void dispose() {
   _timer?.cancel();
   super.dispose();
   }
```

Now for the widgets that need to rebuild when the state changes, just use `ValueListenableBuilder`, See below.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: ListView(
     children: [
      Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
           ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(valueListenable: isStartButtonDisabled, builder: (context, value, child)=> GFButton(
              onPressed:value ? null : startWorkout,
              text: "Start Workout",
            )),
            ValueListenableBuilder<String>(valueListenable: _elapsedTime, builder: (context, value, child)=>  Text(
              value,
            )),
```

In this way when `_elapsedTime` changes, only the `Text` widget is rebuilt, similarly, when `isStartButtonDisabled` changes, only `GFButton` is rebuilt.

Also remember to cancel the `Timer` when you stop the `StopWatch`.

Answer (score 2):

i cannot reproduce your problem from your provided code, but having multiple encapsuled futureBuilders shouldn't be a problem.

Any chance that the `setState` gets called from within one of your future(Builder)s?

That would trigger a rebuild, reloading the future and then setting the state again, triggering a rebuilt, and so on

Comment: I have a setState in Form I am not sure if it is the reason for the error. I have added it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining and calling a function in your build method with is getting called every time you set state, which is occuring at every tick of your timer.

```
() {
  final Map<String,dynamic> arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String,dynamic>;final 
  int id =arguments['id'] ?? 0;
  print("This is the id $id");
  return APIService.Get_Old_Model_No(id);
}()
```